# Applications of Galois cohomology outside number theory

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, galois-cohomology

I'm giving a talk on Galois cohomology, but the majority if not all audience members do not work in number theory - the talk is part of a seminar on group cohomology generally.

As such, I'm looking for resources (papers, monographs, lecture notes) that provide good examples of applications of Galois cohomology outside of number theory, such as for example representation theory. I can think of two applications myself:

- Descent (outside number theory) and its relation to Galois cohomology
- The Brauer group concerning Morita equivalence, which can be calculated using Galois cohomology

Comment: See https://homepage.univie.ac.at/dietrich.burde/papers/chevalley_project_2010.pdf and references therein.

Comment: @markvs this seems more like an introduction to Galois cohomology, what references there are relevant? Most of the references are introductory texts on separate subjects or on homological algebra.

Comment: See references about cohomology of profinite groups. I guess this is where it is applied most outside Number Theory (I may be wrong).

Comment: Why not an application to Galois theory (hence the name!) itself ? For example Hilbert's thm. 90.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo yes I've included that since I made this question and done more research myself